# How to set class property as class method return type?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I got a class A who has a class method and take it's class property as return type.

And a got a class B who inherit from class A.

How to set `get_instance` return type in A and to inform B get the right type?

```py
# typings.py
from typing import TypeVar, Type

AType = TypeVar("AType", bound="A")

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)


class A:
    TYPE = int

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls: Type[AType]) -> "AType.TYPE":
        return cls.TYPE()


class B(A):
    TYPE = str


a = B.get_instance()

reveal_type(a)
```

```sh
mypy typings.py

typings.py:12: error: Name "AType.TYPE" is not defined
typings.py:17: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[str]", base class "A" defined the type as "Type[int]")
typings.py:22: note: Revealed type is "Any"
```

Comment: `cls.TYPE` can be changed to anything. So other desription than `Any` wouldn't be correct, IMHO.

Comment: You have a typo - `get_instace` should be `get_instance`

Comment: Do you need ``A`` to be a concrete class with a concrete ``TYPE``?

Comment: @VPfB `Any` is right, but `cls.TYPE` is fixed when I call a subclass `get_instance` method

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, A and its subclass must have a concrete TYPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Parameterise* over the `TYPE` by making the class `Generic`. This allows to refer to the class attribute `TYPE` and the return type with the same type variable:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Generic

T = TypeVar("T", str, int)


class Base(Generic[T]):
    TYPE: Type[T]

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls: "Type[Base[T]]") -> "T":
        return cls.TYPE()
```

Note that this prevents setting `TYPE` directly. A separate generic `Base` and concrete `A` definition is needed.

```
class A(Base[int]):
    TYPE = int

class B(Base[str]):
    TYPE = str
```